# Java object ot CSV conversion for RedHat Fuse ESB

Tags: java, fuseesb, jbossfuse

Which API i Should use to map java object to CSV or vice versa. I am using RedHat Fuse IDE.

Answer (score 0):

apache camel bindy is the best api to work with CSV and POJO mapping. 
http://camel.apache.org/bindy.html

here you can find the example code 
https://svn.apache.org/repos/asf/camel/trunk/components/camel-bindy/src/test